# Por alguna razón, mi consulta devuelve sumas de faltas incorrectamente

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos de un mundial en la que quiero hacer una consulta de las selecciones con menos faltas.

Tengo una categorización personas-jugadores. **Jugadores** se conecta a **Juegan** y de ahí a la agrupación de una autorelación de **Selección** usando **Contra**. **Jugadores** también se conecta a **Selección** por medio de **Pertenecen**.

Uruguay y Argentina me tendría que dar 4 faltas pero por alguna razón no me da.
Aquí he publicado la base de datos borrando las tablas e inserts no necesarios.

```sql
create database mundial;
use mundial;
drop database mundial;

create table personas(
    ci int,
    nombre varchar(20),
    apellido varchar(20),
    fecha_de_nacimiento date,
    telefono int,
    nacionalidad varchar (30),
    primary key (ci)
);

create table jugadores(
    ci int,
    cod_jugador int,
    posicion varchar(25),
    num_camiseta int,
    foreign key (ci)
    references personas(ci),
    primary key (ci, cod_jugador)
);

create table seleccion(
    cod_seleccion int,
    nombre varchar(25),
    posicion int,
    goles int,
    grupo char,
    puntos int,
    primary key (cod_seleccion)
);
    
create table contra(
    cod_seleccion1 int,
    cod_seleccion2 int,
    fase int,
    hora time, 
    fecha date,
    ganador varchar (25),
    primary key (cod_seleccion1, cod_seleccion2, fase)
);

drop table contra;

create table dirigen(
    ci int,
    cod_tecnico int,
    cod_seleccion int,
    fecha_de_ingreso date,
    foreign key (ci, cod_tecnico) 
    references cuerpo_tecnico (ci, cod_tecnico),
    foreign key (cod_seleccion)
    references seleccion (cod_seleccion),
    primary key (ci, cod_tecnico)
);

create table pertenecen(
    ci int,
    cod_jugador int,
    cod_seleccion int,
    fecha_de_ingreso date,
    foreign key (ci, cod_jugador)
    references jugadores (ci, cod_jugador),
    foreign key (cod_seleccion)
    references  seleccion (cod_seleccion),
    primary key (ci, cod_jugador)
);

create table juegan(
    ci int,
    cod_jugador int,
    fase int,
    cod_seleccion1 int,
    cod_seleccion2 int,
    goles int,
    asistencias int,
    faltas int,
    amonestaciones int,
    capitan boolean,  
    foreign key (ci) 
    references jugadores (ci),
    foreign key (cod_seleccion1)
    references seleccion (cod_seleccion),
    foreign key (cod_seleccion2) 
    references seleccion (cod_seleccion),
    primary key (ci, cod_jugador, fase)
);

insert into personas (ci, nombre, apellido, fecha_de_nacimiento, telefono, nacionalidad)
  VALUES ('1234567', 'Pedro', 'González', '1996-02-14', 5555555, 'Uruguayo'),
    ('2345678', 'Luis', 'Chávez', '1992-11-27', 4444444, 'Mexicano'),
    ('2335678', 'Ruben', 'Borges', '2005-08-30', '999999', 'Argentino'),
    ('3456789', 'Marcelo', 'Silva', '1994-08-03', 3333333, 'Español'),
    ('4567890', 'Manuel', 'Pérez', '1995-06-21', 2222222, 'Colombiano'),
    ('5678901', 'Ricardo', 'Rojas', '1993-04-09', 1111111, 'Brasileño'),
    ('6789012', 'Diego', 'González', '1998-05-12', 6666666, 'Uruguayo'),
    ('7890123', 'Gustavo', 'Rodríguez', '1997-03-15', 7777777, 'Argentino');
    
insert into jugadores (ci, cod_jugador, posicion, num_camiseta)
  values ('4567890', '984411', 'volante', '7'),
    ('5678901', '897498', 'defensa central', '4'),
    ('6789012', '145263', 'delantero', '10'),
    ('7890123', '987654', 'mediocampista', '8');

insert into seleccion (cod_seleccion, nombre, posicion, goles, grupo, puntos)
  values (1, 'Uruguay', 1, 2, 'A', 6),
    (2, 'México', 2, 2, 'B', 4),
    (3, 'Argentina', 1, 1, 'A', '6'),
    (4, 'Colombia', 3, 1, 'C', 1),
    (5, 'Brasil', 2, 3, 'B', 6);

insert into contra (cod_seleccion1, cod_seleccion2, fase, hora, fecha, ganador)
  values (1, 3, 1, '18:00', '2023-06-01', 'Argentina'),
    (2, 5, 2, '21:00', '2023-06-10', 'Brasil'),
    (4, 1, 1, '15:00', '2023-06-15', 'Uruguay'),
    (1, 3, 5, '15:00', '2023-06-20', 'Uruguay');
 

insert into pertenecen (ci, cod_jugador, cod_seleccion, fecha_de_ingreso)
  values ('4567890', '984411', 4, '2023-01-01'),
    ('5678901', '897498', 5, '2023-01-01'),
    ('6789012', '145263', 1, '2023-01-01'),
    ('7890123', '987654', 3, '2023-01-01');


insert into juegan (ci, cod_jugador, fase, cod_seleccion1, cod_seleccion2, goles, asistencias, faltas, amonestaciones, capitan)
  values ('4567890', '984411', 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, false),
    ('5678901', '897498', 2, 2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 1, true),
    ('6789012', '145263', 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0, false),
    ('7890123', '987654', 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, true),
    ('6789012', '145263', 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, false ),
    ('7890123', '987654', 5, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, true);
    
-- i)
select sum(ju.faltas) as faltas, s.nombre, s.cod_seleccion
from juegan ju
join contra c on (c.cod_seleccion1 = ju.cod_seleccion1 or c.cod_seleccion1 = ju.cod_seleccion2) and (c.cod_seleccion2 = ju.cod_seleccion1 or c.cod_seleccion2 = ju.cod_seleccion2) and c.fase = ju.fase
join seleccion s on (c.cod_seleccion1 = s.cod_seleccion or c.cod_seleccion2 = s.cod_seleccion) and (c.cod_seleccion2 = s.cod_seleccion or c.cod_seleccion2 = s.cod_seleccion)
join pertenecen pe on s.cod_seleccion = pe.cod_seleccion
join jugadores j on j.cod_jugador = pe.cod_jugador
group by s.nombre
order by 

sum(ju.faltas) asc
limit 10;
```

Comment: +1 por proporcionar un [repro].

Comment: Si el teléfono es int, por qué hay teléfonos entre comillas `'55555'`? Igual, uno no suma teléfonos, debería ser un varchar. Y en ese script hay FK que no compilan. El drop de `contra` supongo que tampoco va

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo varias cosas de tu modelo de datos.

- No entiendo por qué tienes el ci y el cod_jugador en todas partes.
- No entiendo la tabla juegan. Un jugador puede cambiar de selección durante el torneo? De otra forma, la pertenencia no estaría en los partidos y no le añades al evento *jugador juega un partido* el dato *jugador hace parte de uno de los equipos en el partido*. Hay un montón de datos repetidos a través de la BD

En general, es un diseño que hace todo innecesariamente difícil. Por ejemplo, eso que pides sale sólo con

```
select 
  sum(ju.faltas) as faltas, 
  c1.nombre
from juegan ju
left join pertenecen p on (ju.cod_jugador = p.cod_jugador)
left join seleccion c1 on (p.cod_seleccion = c1.cod_seleccion)
group by c1.cod_seleccion
order by faltas desc
limit 10;
```

Como ves, simplemente se toma el identificador del jugador, se cruza con la pertenencia y ahí llegas a la selección para poder agrupar por selección.
Lo de cod_seleccion1 y cod_seleccion2 es ruido.

Comment: Debería comenzar a identificar las entidades que intenta representar con su DB (obviamente las minimas para los requisitos de su sistema) y después identificar las relaciones entre ellas. De ultima 'Juegan' debería llamarse 'Partido', además de evitar toda la redundancia que existe en su diseño.

Comment: Ay casuita gracias funcionó. Pero necesito la tabla juegan porque ahí almaceno los datos individuales de cada jugador en cada partido.

Comment: @FordGT es que no digo que la quites. De hecho la estoy usando en la respuesta. Pero esas columnas cod_seleccion no van ahí